# ajax query not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" >
            <form method="post" >
              <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="city">
              <input type="submit"  value="Search" id="searchid"/>
            </form>
        <script>
           $("#searchid").click(function() {
           var city=$("#city").val();
           $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           data:city,
           url:'mm.php',
           success:function(data) {
           alert(data);
             }
            });
          });
         </script>
```

I am new to javascript.I want to search a city in google map using ajax query.But  my ajax query is not working properly.It does not opening the given url.

Comment: any errors in console? also try adding an error function.

Answer (score 0):

Your Submit button is inside an html form. When you click this button you need to prevent the entire form to be posted, in order to be able to run your Ajax instead. Try this...

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchid" onclick="javascript: return false;" />
```

Apart from that, what Mayk pointed out is also correct. The parameter for sending city needs to have a name. With these two changes your code worked for me when calling an Http Handler created in .Net.